# PHP infinitely repeats first MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code that I've been working on and when I run it I get the first result 10 times (it used to repeat infinitely until I added the if statement). It's supposed to return the first 10 results. I've looked at a couple other similar questions but none of the solutions on those worked here. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('XXXXXXXXX.com', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXX');
$db = mysql_select_db('a1007515_troop1', $link);
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `pid` DESC LIMIT 10;')))
{
$authinfo = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '.$row['aid'].' LIMIT 1'));
echo '
<div class="content">
<a href="post.007?pid='.$row['pid'].'"><h1 class="title">'.$row['title'].'</h1></a>
<span class="authinfo">This post was made by '.$authinfo['name'].'<i>('.$authinfo['username'].')</i> on '.$row['date'].'.</span>
<p class="txt">'.$row['content'].'</p>
</div>';
if ($i == 10) { break; }
++ $i;
}
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Its best to remove or fake the sensitive data when posting on the web.

Comment: do the mysql_query in while before while condition, store it in a variable, then use the variable in mysql_fetch_array, php.net will give you real examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try simplifying things, try and stick to doing one thing per line, rather than trying to compress it.

Calling `mysql_query` in the `while` will repeat that query every time the while loop is run, rather than fetch the next result. Running another mysql query while iterating through the results of another one can also cause problems.

```
$link = mysql_connect('mysqlwebhost', 'user', 'pass');
$db = mysql_select_db('dbname', $link);

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `posts` p, `users` u WHERE u.id = p.aid  ORDER BY `pid` DESC LIMIT 0,10;');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '
    <div class="content">
    <a href="post.007?pid='.$row['pid'].'"><h1 class="title">'.$row['title'].'</h1></a>
    <span class="authinfo">This post was made by '.$row['name'].'<i>('.$row['username'].')</i> on '.$row['date'].'.</span>
    <p class="txt">'.$row['content'].'</p>
    </div>';
}

mysql_close($link);
```

You may also wish to avoid using mysql_* functions as they have been deprecated. Have a look at either [mysqli or PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: A note to explain why: Everytime the loop do the check it executes the query and bring the results again, so the loop will never finish, since always would be results to fetch, and always the first.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you execute the SQL statement again each time you test the while() condition:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `pid` DESC LIMIT     10;')))
{
...
}
```

The above code will execute this function every time the while() is evaluated:

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `pid` DESC LIMIT     10;')
```

Instead use:

```
$stmt = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stmt)) {
...
}
```

Next you should use a join.  You are following a pattern that "over queries" the database.

You only need the following SQL and a single loop:

```
SELECT u.* 
  FROM `posts` p 
  JOIN `users` u 
    ON u.id = p.aid  
 ORDER BY `pid` DESC 
 LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: Could you explain the last bit of SQL?

Comment: The SQL logically does the same thing that your two queries did.  It gets the 10 most recent rows from the posts table and gets the user row associated with that post based on the aid column from the posts table.  Only the columns from the user table are output.